# Source control binding status is invalid: Visual Studio 2005 and VSS

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visual-sourcesafe, source-control-bindings

I had my VB.NET project and associated solution (developed in Visual Studio 2005) in Visual Source Safe.

Recently started working with another developer and needed to clean up.

Somewhere along the way I broke a binding. I went into

**File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control**

and tried to bind things correctly.

I unbound the project that was incorrectly bound, and tried to rebind it. I have two projects in the solution. This is what I get:

```
Solution/Project       Server Name    Server Binding         Connected     Status

Solution: MySoln.sln   X:\TheSource   $/Tools/MySoln          checked      Valid
Project1               X:\TheSource   $/Tools/MySoln          checked      Valid
Project2               X:\TheSource   $/Tools/MySoln (C:\)    checked     Invalid
```

Where else would I look to try to get the bindings correct?

I may not have given enough information, but this is all I know to give.

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The little question mark button is occasionally helpful.

Needed to check in that project to source control, and the binding became valid.

Comment: First you have to unding project, and then add project to source control. Otherwise VS doesn't show "add project to source control" option.

Answer (score 2):

which version of VSS are you using?

In older versions of Visual SourceSafe (before 6.0c), after adding a solution of Visual Studio to its source control, the binding information was stored directly in the .sln and .proj files.

Since VSS 6.0c, all binding information is kept locally in files named MSSCCPRJ.SCC on the developer's machine.

My guess, the server path for project2 is incorrect. Double check the .prj file is under  $/Tools/MySoln.